# MasterDetailPage + Bottom Tabs in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

Is there a good/efficent way to have a MasterDetailPage (FlyoutPage) while also having shell like tabs at the bottom of the page?

Because I am using Prism I assume that using Shell as well is probably not ideal.

The Gmail and MyAnimeList App are great references for what I am trying to archive.

Comment: Shell contains both, but not sure about Prism.

Comment: Yeah but since i am using Prism i probably shouldnt use shell, I could be wrong though

Answer (score 1):

Prism and shell don't work properly together. You should create a MasterDetail Page, and in it, as part of the detail page, you should add a NavigationPage.

From here, you can try two things inside the NavigationPage

1. a Tabbed page inside the navigation page (I haven't tried this approach though)
2. You could use a normal ContentPage and inside that, add TabView from XamarinCommunity Toolkit

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview

Comment: Thanks for the response.  


1. [Using a TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page#create-a-tabbedpage)
Using TabbedPages as the root page can lead to a poor user experience so I probably cant use that.  
2. I thought about using the XCT TabView as well i just dont like that i need to use ContentViews to populate pages (Which is probably also not ideal considering that I am trying to use Prism modules). Is there a way i can use ContentPages with the XCT TabView

Comment: I think you could try using Prism regions. I don't think you can use multiple content pages in prism with XCT TabView